# How to display group in p-column PrimeNG table?

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

```
list:{"oringinData":"sa","oringinDataTime":"23/10/18","types": 
 [{"sId":1,"sdate":"28/3","stuff":[{"TypeId":1,"onetype":[{"id":1,"name":"John 
Doe"},{"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}]},{"TypeId":2,"othertype": 
[{"id":2,"company":"A"}]}]},{"sId":2,"sdate":"20/3","stuff": 
[{"TypeId":1,"onetype":[{"id":1,"name":"John F"},{"id":2,"name":"Don E"}]}, 
{"TypeId":2,"othertype":[{"id":2,"company":"D"}]},{"TypeId":3,"othertype": 
[{"id":2,"company":"A"},{"id":2,"company":"B"},{"id":2,"company":"C"}]}]}]}
```

Above is JSON arrary of object I want to group row  data in table by grouping in PrimeNG also after every types want a blank row.

Comment: Do you want to use *datatable* or *turbotable* from PrimeNG ?

Comment: data table and also row after every group

Comment: And you want to group by TypeId ?

Comment: @Antikhippe any of table can be done i tried by both

Comment: @Antikhippe TypeId YES

Comment: I have exact same problem. I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @PunitSachan i tried merging row s by p-table got sccuess but im not able to give row span

Comment: @raginipatil can you explain, how are you merging rows in p-table?

Comment: @PunitSachan i have sorted data as shown in JSON array above,then calculated size for each group and i m assigning it as row span but row span is not working inside p-table.

Comment: @raginipatil I think you can try [attr.colspan]="yourArray.length". This is going to work for both rowspan and colspan.